# La clase construtora que hereda de 'System.Data.Entity.DbContext' no reconoce la clase padre

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Yo tengo una solucion de tipo App Consola (.net Framework) con un modello .edmx data model.

Cuando intento compilar me indica error en la linea que corresponde a la declaracion del constructor:

> inicializa una nueva clase para object .

marcando il nombre   **base**

```
public MyImportEntities(string connectionString): base(connectionString)
```

aqui dejo todo el codigo

```
using System; 
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.Linq; 
using System.Text; 
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace EntityFramework1.Model {
    public partial class MyImportEntities
    {

        public MyImportEntities(string connectionString): base(connectionString)
        {

        }
    } }
```

Answer (score 2):

La clase parcial debe contener el mismo nombre de la conexión (lo vemos en el archivo **`App.config`** en la etiqueta `<connectionStrings>`.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="sqldemoEntities" .../>
```

Quedaría así:

```
namespace EntityFramework1.Model {
    public partial class sqldemoEntities
    {

        public sqldemoEntities(string connectionString): base(connectionString)
        {

        }
    }
}
```